# SQL outer query value into nested subquery join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to do a bit of magic (or stupidity) with this query. I am doing a left join with a rank subquery from outboundsms to inboundsms. The thing is that I need to be able to use the datesent from inboundsms to rank the left joined values from dates before or equal to the inboundsms datesent value. Even being pointed in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *       
INTO #smslogtemp 
FROM dbo.SmsLogs smslogs

SELECT
inboundsms.DateSent 'Reply Date',
inboundsms.SendingPhoneNumber 'Replying Number',
inboundsms.Body 'Reply Message'      ,
outboundsms.DateSent 'Last Reminder',
outboundsms.ReceivingPhoneNumber 'Reminder Number',
outboundsms.Body 'Reminder Message',
FROM #smslogtemp inboundsms
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM 
                    (SELECT sms.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sms.ReceivingPhoneNumber ORDER BY sms.DateSent DESC) rnk          
                    FROM #smslogtemp sms
                    WHERE sms.Direction = 'outbound-api' AND CAST(sms.DateSent AS Date) < DATEADD(Day,1,inboundsms.DateSent) --This is my issue inboundsms is not available at this level.
                    ) sms WHERE sms.rnk = 1) outboundsms ON REPLACE(SUBSTRING(outboundsms.ReceivingPhoneNumber,3,10),'-','') = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(inboundsms.SendingPhoneNumber,3,10),'-','')
WHERE inboundsms.Direction = 'inbound' AND com.linkid_c = c.uniqueid_c AND CAST(inboundsms.DateSent AS Date) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate ORDER BY 11, inboundsms.Datesent ASC
```

Sample Data:

| id | Body | DateSent | Direction | SendingPhoneNumber | ReceivingPhoneNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 289b7fab-e132-4507-ae10-4d24c30aee41 | Appointment Reminder 01/13 | 2021-01-12 09:31:44.893 | outbound-api | (917)555-5555 | (918)999-9999 |
| 38fa1f05-50c0-4199-a375-444a17fc7aff | I missed my last appointment! | 2021-01-11 10:30:00.000 | inbound | (918)999-9999 | (917)555-5555 |
| 679798df-54a1-4822-b84d-2c03099c119c | I need to reschedule this appointment | 2021-01-11 10:00:00.000 | inbound | (918)888-8888 | (917)555-5555 |
| f7a5439e-0438-4b46-a711-7ca598b4d76d | Appointment Reminder 01/11 | 2021-01-10 09:31:44.893 | outbound-api | (917)555-5555 | (918)888-8888 |
| f873b5a3-9308-4b1d-b1ae-40c8bd42a600 | Appointment Reminder 01/10 | 2021-01-09 09:31:44.893 | outbound-api | (917)555-5555 | (918)888-8888 |
| f29083e5-5d82-4f8a-a7da-20ec87249ff7 | Appointment Reminder 01/09 | 2021-01-08 09:31:44.893 | outbound-api | (917)555-5555 | (918)888-8888 |
| 32d4ac05-7959-4fbd-8f65-24e7c6e93342 | Appointment Reminder 01/08 | 2021-01-07 09:31:44.893 | outbound-api | (917)555-5555 | (918)888-8888 |
| 8ea99393-cd95-4deb-96be-b5698744aa65 | Appointment Reminder 01/07 | 2021-01-06 09:31:44.893 | outbound-api | (917)555-5555 | (918)999-9999 |

Expected Results:

| Reply Date | Replying Number | Reply Message | Last Reminder | Reminder Number | Reminder Message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-11 10:30:00.000 | (918)999-9999 | I missed my last appointment! | 2021-01-06 09:31:44.893 | (918)999-9999 | Appointment Reminder 01/07 |
| 2021-01-11 10:00:00.000 | (918)888-8888 | I need to reschedule this appointment | 2021-01-10 09:31:44.893 | (918)888-8888 | Appointment Reminder 01/11 |

Comment: Make it possible to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up extracting the two tables from the main query to allow for the left joined table to have access to the column in the primary table. Once this happens I can then bring it back in as a left join and have it properly rank the data.

```
SELECT id,DateSent,SendingPhoneNumber,Body,Direction        
    INTO #inboundsmslogtemp 
    FROM dbo.SmsLogs smslogs
WHERE Direction = 'inbound'

SELECT smslogs.id,smslogs.Body,smslogs.DateSent,smslogs.ReceivingPhoneNumber, inboundsms.id inboundsmsid
    INTO #outboundsmslogtemp
    FROM dbo.SmsLogs smslogs
JOIN ##inboundsmslogtemp inboundsms ON REPLACE(SUBSTRING(smslogs.ReceivingPhoneNumber,3,10),'-','') = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(inboundsms.SendingPhoneNumber,3,10),'-','')
WHERE CAST(smslogs.DateSent AS DATE) <= inboundsms.DateSent AND smslogs.Direction = 'outbound-api'
ORDER BY smslogs.DateSent DESC

SELECT
inboundsms.DateSent 'Reply Date',
inboundsms.SendingPhoneNumber 'Replying Number',
inboundsms.Body 'Reply Message'      ,
outboundsms.DateSent 'Last Reminder',
outboundsms.ReceivingPhoneNumber 'Reminder Number',
outboundsms.Body 'Reminder Message'
FROM #smslogtemp inboundsms
LEFT JOIN (SELECT outboundsms.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY outboundsms.inboundsmsid ORDER BY outboundsms.DateSent DESC) rnk 
            FROM #outboundsmslogtemp outboundsms) outboundsms ON inboundsms.id = outboundsms.inboundsmsid AND outboundsms.rnk = 1
WHERE inboundsms.Direction = 'inbound' AND com.linkid_c = c.uniqueid_c AND CAST(inboundsms.DateSent AS Date) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate ORDER BY 11, inboundsms.Datesent ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to the join --
see below first version is wrong but was left in -- see comments

```
SELECT
  inboundsms.DateSent 'Reply Date',
  inboundsms.SendingPhoneNumber 'Replying Number',
  inboundsms.Body 'Reply Message'      ,
  outboundsms.DateSent 'Last Reminder',
  outboundsms.ReceivingPhoneNumber 'Reminder Number',
  outboundsms.Body 'Reminder Message',
FROM #smslogtemp inboundsms
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT sms.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sms.ReceivingPhoneNumber ORDER BY sms.DateSent DESC) rnk          
  FROM #smslogtemp sms
  WHERE sms.Direction = 'outbound-api' 
) outboundsms on CAST(outboundsms.DateSent AS Date) < DATEADD(Day,1,inboundsms.DateSent)
  AND REPLACE(SUBSTRING(outboundsms.ReceivingPhoneNumber,3,10),'-','') = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(inboundsms.SendingPhoneNumber,3,10),'-','')
  AND outboundsms.rnk = 1
WHERE inboundsms.Direction = 'inbound' AND com.linkid_c = c.uniqueid_c AND CAST(inboundsms.DateSent AS Date) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate ORDER BY 11, inboundsms.Datesent ASC
```

Update below to fix the problem identified in the comments.  I left both versions so it was clear the change.

```
SELECT
  inboundsms.DateSent 'Reply Date',
  inboundsms.SendingPhoneNumber 'Replying Number',
  inboundsms.Body 'Reply Message'      ,
  outboundsms.DateSent 'Last Reminder',
  outboundsms.ReceivingPhoneNumber 'Reminder Number',
  outboundsms.Body 'Reminder Message',
FROM #smslogtemp inboundsms
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT * 
  FROM (
    -- need this sub-query to make sure the rnk column is correct
    SELECT sms.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sms.ReceivingPhoneNumber ORDER BY sms.DateSent DESC) rnk          
    FROM #smslogtemp sms
    WHERE sms.Direction = 'outbound-api'
  ) subquery 
) outboundsms on CAST(outboundsms.DateSent AS Date) < DATEADD(Day,1,inboundsms.DateSent)
  AND REPLACE(SUBSTRING(outboundsms.ReceivingPhoneNumber,3,10),'-','') = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(inboundsms.SendingPhoneNumber,3,10),'-','')
  AND outboundsms.rnk = 1
WHERE inboundsms.Direction = 'inbound' AND com.linkid_c = c.uniqueid_c AND CAST(inboundsms.DateSent AS Date) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate ORDER BY 11, inboundsms.Datesent ASC
```

Comment: Sadly doing it this way drops expected results. My guess is because the `CAST(outboundsms.DateSent AS Date) < DATEADD(Day,1,inboundsms.DateSent)` is happening after they have already been ranked and the rank 1 does not necessarily have a date that is before receiving the inbound text. The reminders continue past the received inbound text, we just want to know when the last reminder before receiving a reply was.

Comment: @Noobiedamus -- ok good point do the ranking in a sub query and then do that join

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge but I am not sure how you mean. Do you mean do a secondary query totally outside of this query and then left join that in?

Comment: @Noobiedamus -- sure I put in a new version to show you what i meant.

Comment: Sadly same results with the second query. I am now trying to break it down now into 3 queries two temp tables with inbound and outbound (with filtering from inbound date sent) and then trying to join outbound back in with a rank in the main query.